# Create file in installation folder using WiX custom action

Tags: wix, custom-action

I try to create a [wix](/questions/tagged/wix) installer that has the need to create a file in the programme folder after Installation. For doing so, I have created a custom action, but I now have the following problem:

In order to write the file, I need to know the installation directory from `session["INSTALLDIR"]`, which is only available if the action is executed `"immediate"`.

However, if i run "immediate" after "install files", the target directory does not yet exist. If I run "deferred", it exists, but i cannot access `session["INSTALLDIR"]`.

If I run "immediate" after "InstallFinalize", I can get the variable and the directory exists, but I am not elevated and hence not allowed to write the file.

What is the correct combination for writing a file to the installation directory?

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: It is actually an XML configuration file - and I already found out about `util:XmlFile` ;-) +1 for having the right thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CustomActionData to access property values from a deferred CA. You need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233267/how-to-pass-customactiondata-to-a-customaction-using-wix)

or

[another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835624/how-do-i-pass-msiexec-properties-to-a-wix-c-sharp-custom-action)

Comment: Thanks - if you are new to WiX, it is difficult to find the right question to put into a search engine...

Answer (score 1):

Beyond using a built in extension for custom actions instead of writing your own, the next level would be  how can I move complexity / custom actions out of the installer?

One thought is to write it to the registry instead.  Another thought is for the application reading the value to be able to determine installation directory on it's own.   One possibility is reflection to get the location another possibility is to query the MSI API for where the product is installed.