# How can I create file in WIX Toolset

Tags: windows, wix

I am trying to use WiX to make a installer. Now I want to create a new file in install location. (A configuration contains install location written in JSON).

I created a custom action, and I past install location to my action like this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="InstallChromeExtension.SetProperties" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
        <Custom Action="InstallChromeExtension" After="CostFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="InstallChromeExtension" BinaryKey="ExtensionActionDll" DllEntry="InstallAction" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="no" Return="check" />
    <CustomAction Id="InstallChromeExtension.SetProperties" Property="InstallChromeExtension" Value="INSTALLLOCATION=[INSTALLLOCATION]" Execute="immediate" />
    <Binary Id="ExtensionActionDll" SourceFile="ExtensionAction.dll" />
</Fragment>
```

And I used `CreateFile` to create a new file, but Error 3 I got.

I google it said must set action as deferred, and I cannot get install location in deferred action. Can you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "install location dynamic"?

Comment: I am sorry my poor English. I mean I want to create a new file in install location.

Comment: Perhaps this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24809593/4634044

Comment: Oh, I think I it can help me, think you very much! @linuxrocks