# How to solve error in msi package creation using electron wix creator with error logging?

Tags: node.js, go, npm, electron, electron-wix-msi

I am trying to create a msi package from golang program with error logging feature. So, that I will be able to retrieve golang app crash logs.

The following Golang code is saved to `main.go`, with a crash expected due to `1\0` division related error.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // intentionally cause a divide-by-zero error
    x := 0
    y := 1 / x
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

Then I was trying to create msi package using following steps:

- step 1: `go get github.com/akavel/rsrc`
- step 2: `rsrc -ico .\abc.ico`
- step 3: `$Env:GOOS="windows"; go build -ldflags "-H windowsgui" -o ABC.exe`
- step 4: `npm install electron-wix-msi@latest`
- step 5: `npm install node-gyp@latest --save-dev`
- step 6: `npm install child_process@latest --save-dev`
- step 7: `npm install fs@0.0.1-security --save-dev`
- step 8: `npm i exe-icon-extractor@latest --save-dev`

Then I have created a javascript file name `msi_creator.js` to generate msi package. The javascript code is as below:

```js
const { MSICreator } = require("electron-wix-msi");
const path = require("path");
const { execSync } = require("child_process");

async function start() {
  try {

    // Step 2: Instantiate the MSICreator
    const msiCreator = new MSICreator({
      appDirectory: path.resolve("."),
      description: "ABC",
      exe: "ABC.exe",
      name: "ABC",
      manufacturer: "FFFF",
      version: "0.1.0",
      upgradeCode: "{12343238-1111-2222-3333-123483275556}",
      removeExistingProduct: true,
      iconPath: "./abc.ico",
      outputDirectory: path.resolve("./output/"),
    });

    // Step 4: Create a .wxs template file
    console.log("Creating the .wxs template file...");
    await msiCreator.create();
    console.log("Created the .wxs template file.");

    // Step 5: Define the MSIErrorLog DLL function
    console.log("Defining the MSIErrorLog DLL function...");
    msiCreator.defineMsiErrorLogFunction(
      function MSIErrorLog(hInstall) {
        var exePath = session.property('CustomActionData');
        var errorLogFile = session.property('MsiErrorLogFile');
        try {
          var child_process = require('child_process');
          child_process.execFile(exePath, {stdio: 'ignore'}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
              var fs = require('fs');
              var logFile = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.env['TEMP'], 'msi_error.log'), {flags: 'a'});
              logFile.write('Error: ' + error.message + '\n');
              logFile.end();
            }
          });
        } catch (e) {
          var fs = require('fs');
          var logFile = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.env['TEMP'], 'msi_error.log'), {flags: 'a'});
          logFile.write('Error: ' + e.message + '\n');
          logFile.end();
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("Defined the MSIErrorLog DLL function.");

    // Step 6: Compile the template to a .msi file
    console.log("Compiling the .wxs template...");
    await msiCreator.compile();
    console.log("Compiled the .wxs template to an MSI installer.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

start();
```

Then I run the command

```
node .\msi_creator.js
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Created the .wxs template file.
Defining the MSIErrorLog DLL function...
TypeError: msiCreator.defineMsiErrorLogFunction is not a function
```

How to fix this issue? How can I store error logs related app crash?

Thanks and Regards,
manu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the [`electron-wix-msi` module does not seem to include a `defineMsiErrorLogFunction()` function](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aelectron-userland%2Felectron-wix-msi%20defineMsiErrorLogFunction%20&type=code), it is not surprising to get "`TypeError: msiCreator.defineMsiErrorLogFunction is not a function`".

You could instead include in your `.wsx` file a directive to:

- call `ABC.exe` and log any error
- do so after the installation

```xml
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunCollectLogs" After="InstallFinalize" />
  ...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<Product>
  <Binary Id="CollectLogs" SourceFile="collect_logs.js" />
  <CustomAction Id="RunCollectLogs" BinaryKey="CollectLogs" ExeCommand="node collect_logs.js" Execute="deferred" />
  ...
</Product>
```

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835764/6309), a custom action needs to be a deferred custom action in order to run after `InstallFiles`.

With `collect_logs.js`:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const logPath = path.join(process.env["TEMP"], "msi_error.log");

exec("ABC.exe", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    const logFile = fs.createWriteStream(logPath, { flags: "a" });
    logFile.write("Error: " + error.message + "\n");
    logFile.end();
  }
});
```

Comment: I have modified my code with custom actions sections as below to run custom actions to collect logs:

```javascript 
customActions: [
      {
        id: "runABC",
        directory: "INSTALLDIR",
        executable: "cmd.exe",
        arguments: [
          "/c",
          "start",
          "cmd.exe",
          "/c",
          "node",
          "collect_logs.js",
        ],
        execute: "immediate",
        logDescription: "Running custom_act.js after installation",
      },
    ],
```
I am not seeing any crash logs. What is wrong with my set up?

Comment: @manoos Did you try the `collect_logs.js` I suggested?  The issue with your approach is that it will run the command script during the installation, and not after the installation is completed.